# I uninstall DNSUnlocker, but its adware still terrorizes my PC

Tags: virus-removal, adware

These DNSUnlocker things are everywhere on every page on my PC. I don't even know how it even got on my system. After finding it in control panel and uninstalling it, it seems to still terrorize my pc, with most words becoming links for "ads" which is really annoying when trying to click play on one of my games.

I won't be able to add images because the images button has been taken over by the adware.

How can I stop this "DNS Unlocker" adware from messing up my PC?

Comment: Sadly I can't check, this adware has taken over the link.

Comment: You need to be working from a different machine anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Following this [site](http://botcrawl.com/dns-unlocker-virus-removal/), downloading `Malwarebytes` should do the trick and completely remove it. If you have trouble, there's a [direct link](https://store.malwarebytes.org/342/cookie?affiliate=23046&redirectto=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloads.malwarebytes.org%2Ffile%2Fmbam%2F&redirecthash=79CD12ECAB939D32967B5D05C6C86E32) to the installer. There seems to be another way (the manual way), but I'd try this one as the final shot.